# How is it possible that for infinite L in R exists subset L' which is not in Re?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, decision-problem, computation-models, semi-decidability

Proove that for every infinite $L \in R$ there is a $L' \subseteq L$ s.t $L' \notin  RE$.

How can I proove it? if sketched on venn diagram it doesn't make sense...

[image]

From my point of view everything that is in R suppose to be in Re. $x \in A $ and $A \subseteq B$ then $x \in B$. Why does it fail? and how am I suppose to proove it?

Comment: And would you think that since $\Sigma^*\in R$ then all languages are also in $R$? The property of being decidable isn't retained by set containment

Comment: @nirshahar Can I write it as a proof? "The property of being decidable isn't retained by set containment " thus there is L' which is not in Re?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\in R$, then you don't necessarily know *anything* about whether $A\in R$ or $A\notin R$.

Answer (score 2):

Subsets of recursive languages aren't always recursive or recursively enumerable. The simplest example is the language of all strings: it is clearly recursive (even regular), and all languages are its subsets including those not in $RE$.

To solve this question, consider this: how many subsets does an infinite language $L$ have? What does that imply regarding their membership in $RE$?